# How to convert vector to array and access it

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I need to convert a std::vector to an array. I try with this simple code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

vector<double> v;
double* a = &v[0];


for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
v.push_back(i);

cout<<"Value -V- 9: "<<v[9]<<endl;
cout<<"Value -a- 9: "<<a[9]<<endl; //Gives me segmentation fault error

return 0;
}
```

i read on another discussion this way to convert a vector to an array, but now i also need to access a single element of my array (in this way compiler gives me error of segmentation fault). I'm quite new in c++ and maybe this method is totally wrong. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior on the second line in `main()`. You're requesting the address of an element that doesn't exist yet in your vector. Move that second line *after* your insertion loop.

Comment: quite obviously :) txs WhozCraig

Comment: @WhozCraig what's worse, it's not the only UB and in fact I don't think it's the significant one. The pointers to the elements of a vector are invalidated after an insertion, and probably that's what causing the problem.

Comment: @H2CO3 An invalid pointer becomes *really* invalid because of the follow-up insertions. Ok, thats a new one. =P

Comment: @WhozCraig (of course, since we are in UB-land, that's just pointless speculation after all :P)

Comment: whozcraig, your answer is correct so I'm not sure why you posted that as a comment.

Comment: @shawn1874 because this is not worth an answer. there are already endless duplicates of this - pretty trivial - problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, you should understand how std::vector works: it is a self-expanding array, it can reallocate its internal storage whenever it needs.
A right way to get a pointer to internal array is to call std::vector::data member (available only in C++11):

```
double * a = v.data();
```

Note that this pointer is valid only until you modify the vector.
Just in case, "convert" here doesn't mean real conversion, the vector isn't modified and no new arrays are created. Only a pointer to the data stored in std::vector is received.

Comment: Before C++11 you can do &(v[0]) to get the data pointer. std::vector (almost?) has to be implemented as a contiguous array and indeed it is in all standard libraries I'm aware of.

Comment: This post is partially incorrect.  A modification to an existing element of a vector does not invalid the address previously returned by &v[0].  Calling a member function to get the address is no more or less safe then using the data member, because it doesn't even throw an exception if the memory hasn't been allocated.

Comment: @shawn1874: you are right, I seemed to mean something like "modification of the vector's size". Calling a member function just is more readable and doesn't look like exploiting implementation details (&v[0] is not "exploiting implementation details", as since c++11 vector must be implemented as a continuous array, but it look like, as for me).

Answer (score 0):

```
double* a = &v[0];
```

The answer was already posted in comments, but the bottom line is that you are initializing a to an invalid address because at that point within the program the vector has no data.  To make your example work, you need to set the pointer a after the loop has finished.  The vector might reallocate during insertions so you cannot trust a raw pointer after an insertion.  In this case, a never pointed to anything valid.

Normally, the ability to get the address of an element is used in combination with older interfaces that require raw pointers.  If you are writing new C++ code, it is always preferable to use the interface of the container to get data.  Prefer iterators over raw pointers, and read about how iterators might be invalidated by certain kinds of operations.